# Choice of X-ray scatterer in Compton effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

I am going to perform an experiment on Compton Scattering, and I am going to use an X-ray scatterer to scatter the incident X-rays. I have been instructed that Acrylic Glass slab are the best for this purpose. I am not sure if it is because the acrylic glass slab does not have any free electrons present or any other reason. Please explain.